# O que tem de errado com esse código python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import urllib.request
import time

def send_to_twitter():
    import sys
    import tweepy
    CONSUMER_KEY = '1wrnsF5lB8fEWVzRdvlIqdTl'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'eTiylDUHLJgGnTCcxzzCtzHXG4OlHrbY6wLvuZUnAEhrokyNA'
    ACCESS_KEY = '2325915097-q2JYaZ3UGeL9Pr95BJC7643NMyETY6x7Bb8T1q'
    ACCESS_SECRET = '8GRq4e9ukVKcC8XjroM3iLKuZYOM2QtFEdCHXG3TXx0z'
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    api.update_status(msg)

def get_price():
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://beans-r-us.appspot.com/prices-loyalty.html")
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")
    where = text.find('>$')
    start_of_price = where + 2
    end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
    return(text[start_of_price : end_of_price])

escolha = input("Precisa do valor imediatamente? ")

if escolha == 'y':
    send_to_twitter(get_price())
else:
    if escolha == 'n':
        price = 99.99
        while price > 4.74:
            price = float(get_price())
            time.sleep(3)
        send_to_twitter('BUY!')
    else:
        print("Voce nao escolheu nada")
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(livro)programa_com_escolha_cafe.py", line 34, in <module>
    send_to_twitter('BUY!')
TypeError: send_to_twitter() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Voce esta dando um argumento em uma função que não recebe argumento.

Answer (score 7):

Seu código está produzindo o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: send_to_twitter() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Analisando a mensagem, vemos que este é um `TypeError`, que nos diz que a função `send_to_twitter()` deve receber 0 argumentos, mas no entanto, você passou 1 argumento ao escrever o termo `'BUY!'`, dentro de `send_to_twitter('BUY!')`.

---

Logo no início do código, vemos que a função `send_to_twitter()` foi criada sem pedir nenhum argumento.

Tente alterar o trecho:

```
def send_to_twitter():
    import sys
    import tweepy
    ...
```

para

```
def send_to_twitter(msg):
    import sys
    import tweepy
    ...
```

---

Exemplificando...

*Errado:*

```
def imprimirNaTela():
    print msg
```

*Correto:*

```
def imprimirNaTela(msg):
    print msg
```

Comment: +1 nem tinha reparado nesta: `send_to_twitter('BUY!')`